# How to access Hash in Array of Hashes in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, hash

I have what I believe to be a Hash that references an array of hashes. What I am trying to understand is how to access the hash elements within this array of hashes.

EDIT: Here is the full hash structure

```
$VAR1 = {
      'CVE-2015-0677' => {
                         'vuln:references' => [
                                              {
                                                'attr' => {
                                                            'reference_type' => 'VENDOR_ADVISORY',
                                                            'xml:lang' => 'en'
                                                          },
                                                'vuln:source' => 'CISCO',
                                                'vuln:reference' => [
                                                                    {
                                                                      'attr' => {
                                                                                  'href' => 'http://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20150408-asa',
                                                                                  'xml:lang' => 'en'
                                                                                }
                                                                    }
                                                                  ]
                                              }
                                            ],
                         'vuln:published-datetime' => '2015-04-12T21:59:03.033-04:00',
                         'vuln:last-modified-datetime' => '2015-04-13T17:45:18.310-04:00',
                         'vuln:vulnerable-software-list' => [
                                                              'cpe:/o:cisco:adaptive_security_appliance_software:9.0.3',
                                                              'cpe:/o:cisco:adaptive_security_appliance_software:8.4.5',
                                                            ],
                         'vuln:summary' => 'The XML parser in Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance (ASA) Software 8.4 before 8.4(7.28), 8.6 before 8.6(1.17), 9.0 before 9.0(4.33), 9.1 before 9.1(6), 9.2 before 9.2(3.4), and 9.3 before 9.3(3), when Clientless SSL VPN, AnyConnect SSL VPN, or AnyConnect IKEv2 VPN is used, allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service (VPN outage or device reload) via a crafted XML document, aka Bug ID CSCus95290.'
                       }
    };
```

If I try the following the output of the first Data::Dumper output is identical to the second.

```
for my $key ( keys $hash ) {
 my @references =  $hash->{$key}{'vuln:references'};
 print Dumper(@references);  #1
  for my $vulnref (@references) {
    print Dumper($vulnref); #2
  }
}

#1
$VAR1 = [
       {
         'vuln:reference' => 'VENDOR',
         'vuln:source' => 'CISCO',
        }
        ];

#2  
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'vuln:reference' => 'VENDOR',
        'vuln:source' => 'CISCO',

      }
    ];
```

So my for loop doesn't seem to be having any affect?

However if I loop through twice then the second loop

```
for my $key ( keys $hash ) {
  my @references =  $hash->{$key}{'vuln:references'};
  print Dumper(@references); #1
  for my $vulnref (@references) {
    for my $vuln ($vulnref) {
       print Dumper($vuln);  #2
    }
   }
}


#1 
$VAR1 = [
       {
        'vuln:reference' => 'VENDOR',
        'vuln:source' => 'CISCO',

      }
    ];

#2
$VAR1 = {
       'vuln:reference' => 'VENDOR',
       'vuln:source' => 'CISCO', 
    };
```

I now seem to be accessing the hash.

I believe I am missing something fundamental here.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please show the output of `print Dumper $hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the topmost level of the hash. The `$VAR1` that you show is the value of `$hash->{key}`, but I can't tell what `key` might be.

Anyway, using what I have,

- `$hash->{key}` is a reference to a *hash* with a single element with the key `vuln:references`
- `$hash->{key}{'vuln:references'}` is a reference to an *array* with a single element at index zero
- `$hash->{key}{'vuln:references'}[0]` is a reference to another *hash*, this time with *two* elements

You don't say what you want to do with this data, but it looks like all you need is

```
my $data = $hash->{key}{'vuln:references'}[0];

for my $key (keys %$data) {
  printf "%s => %s\n", $key, $data->{$key};
}
```

**output**

```
vuln:source => CISCO
vuln:reference => VENDOR
```

---

**Update**

You don't say how `$key` gets defined, but in

```
for my $data ( $hash->{$key}{'vuln:references'} ) { ... }
```

you have written a loop that executes *once* with `$data` set to the array reference that I described above.

To loop over the whole structure, assuming your outermost hash referred to by `$hash` and the inner array are the only layers with multiple elements, you could write

```
for my $cve ( keys %$hash ) {
  my $refs = $hash->{$cve}{'vuln:references'};
  print $cve, " \n";
  for my $ref ( @$refs ) {
    printf "  %s => %s\n", $_, $ref->{$_} for keys %$ref;
    print "\n";
  }
}
```

Notice the *dereferencing* of the structures in `keys %$hash`, `@$refs` and `%$ref`. In more recent versions of Perl you can use `keys $hash` without the dereference, but it is an experimental feature that shouldn't be used in live code, and will produce a warning message if you have `use warnings` in place as you should (together with `use strict`) at the top of your program

As for why your code dumps the same values twice, you have

```
my @references = $hash->{$key}{'vuln:references'};
```

which sets the array `@references` to hold *one element* which is the array reference from the hash at that point. Then

```
print Dumper(@references);
```

dumps each element of the array, one by one. Because there is only one element it outputs only one dump. Finally

```
for my $vulnref (@references) {
  for my $vuln ($vulnref) {
    print Dumper($vuln);
  }
}
```

sets `$vulnref` to each element of `@references`. Because there is only one the loop executes once, with `$vulnref` set to the array reference. Then `$vuln` is set to each element of the list `( $vulnref )` so it takes another copy of the same reference. Finally that value is dumped, with the result that the same array reference as before is displayed.

Remember that Perl scalar values start with `$`; even an element of an array is `$array[0]`, and it is treated as a *single value* even if that value is a reference. If you want to access the data it refers to you must *dereference* it with the appropriate symbol

Comment: Thanks Borodin, I've updated my question to include the original full hash, the key in this case in the 'CVE-2015-0677'. There can be multiple 'CVE' entries but I've just shown one for simplicity. Please note I simplified the structure in my original question of the 'vuln:references' to remove what seemed irrelavent to the question.

Comment: ok, so if I use 'my $data = $hash->{key}{'vuln:references'}[0];' it works, but if I use a for loop instead like so 'for my $data  ($hash->{$key}{'vuln:references'})'  it tells me that '$data' is not a hash reference when I try to access it in the same way as you have described above. What is the difference between the two? I'm still stuck with the same original question. Why does my first for loop not appear to change the data at all?